# Geocoder is not working on Android Phone

Tags: android, geocode

I want to get Address of my current location using android Geocoder API. that works fine on my one phone but same app is not returning any address on my other  phone (Both android 2.3.6 API 10).
 After doing some research i found
On Android Geocoder API documentation it is mentioned that 
The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework.

Can any one let me know what is that service? Why it is not part of android SDK. and how to get that and run on my phone.

Is there any way by which if i check if geocoder is not present then i can start that service programatically.